# Laravel run batch of commands between hours

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There are some commands:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('Events:complete')->everyFiveMinutes();
    $schedule->command('Payments:authorize')->everyFiveMinutes();
    $schedule->command('Requests:processing')->hourly();
}
```

Every one of them should be performed with their own periodicity. But I wanna add one more condition - run that commands only between 08:00 and 20:00. Can Laravel do it, or should I check time via pure php?

**Laravel 5.4**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **between** method. You will find it here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

It would be something like that for you :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('Events:complete')->everyFiveMinutes()->between('08:00', '20:00');
   $schedule->command('Payments:authorize')->everyFiveMinutes()->between('08:00', '20:00');
   $schedule->command('Requests:processing')->hourly()->between('08:00', '20:00');
}
```